# Using a void* as an argument inside a function pointer inside a structure definition causes a syntax error

Tags: c, powerpc, codewarrior

I am creating an interface structure

```
typedef struct Circular_Buffer_Interface_t * Circular_Buffer_Interface;
typedef struct Circular_Buffer_Interface_t {
    U8 (*Put)(Circular_Buffer, void*);
    U8 (*Get)(Circular_Buffer, void*);
    U8 (*Reset)(Circular_Buffer);
    BOOL (*isFull)(Circular_Buffer);
    BOOL (*isEmpty)(Circular_Buffer);
} Circular_Buffer_Interface_t;

typedef struct Circular_Buffer_t * Circular_Buffer;
typedef struct Circular_Buffer_t {
    Circular_Buffer_Interface Interface;
} Circular_Buffer_t;
```

My question is when I try to compile why using void* as a function argument it throws a syntax error.

if I use a typedef
   `typedef void* VoidPtr`

and then use

```
typedef void* VoidPtr;
typedef struct Circular_Buffer_Interface_t {
    U8 (*Put)(Circular_Buffer, VoidPtr);
    U8 (*Get)(Circular_Buffer, VoidPtr);
    U8 (*Reset)(Circular_Buffer);
    BOOL (*isFull)(Circular_Buffer);
    BOOL (*isEmpty)(Circular_Buffer);
} Circular_Buffer_Interface_t;
```

everything complies just fine.

Does anyone have a clue while this is happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What syntax error? Which C compiler / standard? No problems with C99 here: http://ideone.com/6rhO8r

Comment: Of course `Circular_Buffer` should be defined beforehand, and probably be a pointer. Other than that, I agree with @rici.

Comment: I am using  Minimalist GNU for Windows (mingw32) - C99 extensions are enabled

Comment: I get similar from MSVC. Having defined `U8` and `BOOL` as types, your second `struct` definition compiles cleanly. I didn't even need your `typedef void* VoidPtr`. But your first `struct` definition, gives `error C2122: 'void *' : prototype parameter in name list illegal`

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem with mingw32 or MSVC 14. Please provide a complete example, because the error isn't here.

Comment: Also, how is the powerpc tag related if you're using mingw32?

Comment: @WeatherVane: That's the result of using K&R C syntax (accidentally); if you don't define either Circular_Buffer or VoidPtr, then they become argument names with unspecified types.

Comment: @rici You win the prize (and should post an answer to claim said prize). OP has finally added the declaration for `Circular_Buffer`, and it's just as you suggested.

Comment: @rici, Thanks I think you have the right answer. I am just confused as to why it compiled when VoidPtr is defined and Circular_Buffer is not.  Seems like I should get the same error.

Comment: @skipfer0712: Indeed you should. You should need either both or neither to be defined for it to work. (And on even not very recent gcc versions, compiling with `-Wall` will tell you that you're using a deprecated function declaration syntax.)

Comment: @user3386109: Yeah, probably. I posted an answer, anyway. I don't have a good explanation for how it works when VoidPtr is defined, but I don't have the version of gcc OP is using. Or the one being used by WeatherVane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This member declaration

```
U8 (*Put)(Circular_Buffer, VoidPtr);
```

will work fine if neither `Circular_Buffer` nor `VoidPtr` are defined with  `typedef` at that point in the source code. (`U8` must be defined, though.) That's because it will be accepted as a K&R-style function declaration which specifies the names of the parameters but not their types. (That is, `Put` will be declared as a pointer to a function taking two parameters of unspecified type.)

It will also work if both `Circular_Buffer` and `VoidPtr` are defined as `typedef`s, in which case it will be treated as a normal standard C declaration.

If you compile with `-Wall`, the first case will probably produce a warning. `-Wall` is *always* recommended.

It should fail to compile if only one of the two identifiers is declared as a `typedef`, so I don't know how it works in the case where `typedef void* VoidPtr` comes before the member declaration, and `typedef struct ... Circular_Buffer` comes afterwards. Perhaps that's an obscure feature of an old version of gcc. (Once the compiler decides it is a K&R function declaration, the actual parameter names can be ignored unless the it is a function definition, and in the context in which the line appears, it cannot be a function definition.)

Answer (score 0):

The first declaration, with the `void *`, seems perfectly valid C.  I added some code to make this a complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int U8;
typedef int BOOL;
typedef int Circular_Buffer;

typedef struct Circular_Buffer_Interface_t {
    U8 (*Put)(Circular_Buffer, void*);
    U8 (*Get)(Circular_Buffer, void*);
    U8 (*Reset)(Circular_Buffer);
    BOOL (*isFull)(Circular_Buffer);
    BOOL (*isEmpty)(Circular_Buffer);
} Circular_Buffer_Interface_t;

int main() {
    puts("hello");
}
```

This program compiles successfully and without warning with GNU C version 5.2 on MacOSX:

```
> gcc-5 -std=c99 -Wall x.c
> ./a.out
hello
```

The same works with the Apple version of clang.  Thus I suspect that the problem is with your C compiler, rather than with your code.

Comment: Or the problem is with the definition of `Circular_Buffer`.

Comment: Does my code compile for you?  If not, what error message do you get?

Comment: Your code complied.  Can you see my edit on how I defined Circular_Buffer